# Username and password failure in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently trying to make a program that will ask the user for the username and password. If they log off they have to be able to put that password and username back in. no matter how I look at it I keep getting "username and password are incorrect."

```
#Ask user for username and password
def main():
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
    password = input("Please enter a desired password: ")
    save(username, password)

#trys to log user on
def save(username, password):
    if username == "username" and password == "password":
        login(username)
    else:
        print("Username and/or password is incorrect. Please try again!")
        main()

#Welcomes
def login(username):
    print("You have successfully logged in!")
    print()
    print("Welcome user!")
    print()
    commands()

#run a simple output
def commands():

    command = input("What would you like me to do for you today?: ")

    if command == "log off" or command =="quit":
        print("You have logged off")
        main()
    else:
        print("Unknown command")
        commands()
main()
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting already says it all...

Comment: `if username == "username" and password == "password:` <==

Comment: I have updated it and I still get "incorrect username and/or password." I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

C'mon buddy you are checking the username and password for static value.

> ```
>  if username == "username" and password == "password":
> ```

as a result any other username or password is giving you the error:

> Username and/or password is incorrect. Please try again!

try again using "username" for username and "password" for password, you won't definitely get the error.

Comment: @Linkstus thnx man! Its my pleasure helping you!
Approve the answer if it worked! :p